# jQuery Animation

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I made an animation with jQuery, everything is written correctly but it doesn't work!!! DX Could anyone help me?

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
 $('#cloud1').css({backgroundPosition: '0 -80px'});
 $('#cloud2').css({backgroundPosition: '0 -30px'});
  $('#cloud1').animate({backgroundPosition: '(-500px -80px)'}, 20000);
  $('#cloud2').animate({backgroundPosition: '(-625px -30px)'}, 20000);
});
```

Comment: @roXon <3 ;) Thanks. And It I probably will 'cause I played this one game, ROBLOX. I programed on it and there was a Tween function that is extremely similar to this Animation function in jQuery.

Comment: I know roblox! installed once... Look at my answer to see mine! :) And a nice tutorial (still writing pt.3,4,5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see here what can jQuery do. Here is a simple (with fiew bugs to fix) game.
You can find in the code all the jQuery brutality you may need, and is full of loops and other things! Take a look:

http://roxon.in/scripts/particlesExplosionGame/

recommended browsers: Opera, Chrome (both have a great JS engine!)

Or if you want you can go through this easy tutorial of mine (has loops too! counters and all the fun jQuery stuff!) :

http://roxon.in/scripts/tutorials/NavGallery_jQuery_Tutorial_01/

---

But always ... always go for reference to the jQuery official API pages. And Stack Overflow of course.

And take a look for 'bounces' (easings) , sliders and so on here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/

---

Here, I prepared to you a fun

### [DEMO loops animation with random positions and speed](http://jsfiddle.net/eg8mE/)

I commented my code do help you understand!

Change the numbers, add more cars, have fun!

P.S. : to add more cars you'll have to learn the jQuery .each() function method ;) and try to implement it!

(Ok, just kidding - but it's easy. look for your self! [DEMO with multiple cars!](http://jsfiddle.net/eg8mE/2/))

Comment: it took me a few seconds to get into source!

Comment: Why that... hmmmmm My browser is kind. opened in a 0,0031 secs.

Answer (score 2):

Taken from documentation

```
  $("#block").animate({
    width: "70%", 
  }, 1500 );
```

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

will change current width to 70% in 1,5 second

Comment: OH! So that's pretty much the easiest explanation?

Comment: @Michael, If you find all those properties confusing, just try it with a single one, like `width`. Build from there.

Comment: Oh, no I don't.  I don't even know what I meant in that comment. Okay, so what if I wanted to ease it in or out or add bounce?

Comment: Oh, no. I understood it, but where would I add so how the script starts or ends the animation, as in eases in or eases out, bounces in or out, backs in or backs out. That stuff.

Comment: @Michael: better would be to use jquery UI plugin which supports this http://jqueryui.com/

Answer (score 2):

You can't go wrong with the official jQuery API. See [.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).

Comment: Hehe. Sorry. Um, is there a way to loop an animation and in an animation create and remove an object when the animation is finished? Well more like, before the anim. starts, an image is created. When the. anim. is finished, the image is removed. Or restarted?